# jquery button color switch not working

Tags: jquery

I was trying to use `addClass()`, `removeClass()` and `hasClass()` methods. But this small code it is not at all working ?

Saw documentation for all 3 functions. seems it should work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Trials</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .liked
    {
        color:red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<br><br><br>
<button id="like1" class="btn likeBtns liked">5<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></button>

<script>
$('.likeBtns').on('click', function(){

    var x = $(this).attr('id');
    x = "#"+x;
    if($("#like1").hasClass("liked"))
    {
        console.log("has");
        $("#like1").removeClass("liked");
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("doesnt have");
        $("#like1").addClass("liked");
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of checking if something has a class, just use `toggleClass`. It will add the class to the object if it isn't already there, and remove it if it exists.

Comment: nice alternative, I tried right now  but same problem. Did you find any problem in original code?

Comment: Can you check your browser for any console errors? That should point you in the right direction. In your code, the lines mentioning `x` are irrelevant since you have specified a selector after that. The answer below is functional and sounds like it does exactly what you are after. It could be that you think it isn't working because of some styling issues.

Comment: yup, it worked... thanks @Goose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `toggleClass()` like below:-

Working example:-

```js
$('.likeBtns').on('click', function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("liked");
});
```

```css
.liked{
  color:red;
}

.liked:hover,
.liked:focus,
.liked.focus {
    color:red !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Trials</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br><br><br>
    <button id="like1" class="btn likeBtns">5<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note:- The effect will shown when you click on button and then click outside.

it's because your `bootstrap.css` have below css already applied on button:-

```
btn.focus, .btn:focus, .btn:hover {
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

***In my code i have override that `css` code of bootstrap. And now it will work completely fine***

Comment: yes, the problem is with bootstrap, i will override it by some custom class. Kudos for pointing the exact problem !

Comment: @VandanKumbhat  glad to help you. have a great day :):)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the button color completely you need to know that the class ***btn*** has also the [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) and [:focus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) pseudo classes. That means you need to add the .liked:hover and .liked:focus.

The snippet:

```js
$('.likeBtns').on('click', function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('liked')
});
```

```css
.liked
{
    color:red;
}
.liked:hover,
.liked:focus,
.liked.focus {
    color:red !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<button id="like1" class="btn likeBtns liked">5<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span></button>
```